# Why is the process of POS-tagging slow in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp, part-of-speech

I am using OpenNLP for POS-tagging and I found out that this is incredibly slow.

```
  posTagger = PosModelFactory.getPosModel("en");
  String sent[] = new String[]{"Most", "large", "cities", "in", "the", "US", "had",
                             "morning", "and", "afternoon", "newspapers", "."};       
  String tags[] = posTagger .tag(sent);
```

I used this code for a sample of 5 sentences, and this is the time I am getting for PoS in ms.

```
Time taken to pos 27
Time taken to pos 11
Time taken to pos 10
Time taken to pos 11
Time taken to pos 113
```

Is there any way to boost this up. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually measuring? Only the initial setup is slow, the call to `tag()` should be fast. So only setup the tagger once.

Comment: @DanielNaber: I have set up the tagger only once.